# NSString won't add to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

In my app i use

```
[theMutableArray addObject:theString];
```

several times and it works every time, however when trying to add in another view it won't add.

I know my string is not null because i have

```
NSLog(@"%@, %@", theString, theMutableArray);
```

and it returns
"the string value", (null)

In my viewDidLoad i have

```
theMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and where i try to add it I have

```
theString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
[theMutableArray addObject:theString];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", theString, theMutableArray);
```

Is there a typo of any sort? or did i forget something?

Comment: You can not add anything to array if it is not created (= nil).

Comment: It is deallocated at the end of the method. I think you mean to make your array an `@property` so that your class has a reference to it and you can access beyond the method where you initialized it.

Comment: @JoePasq Tried @property(nonatomic, strong) for my mutable array, theres no difference

Comment: have you been accessing it with `self.theMutableArray`?

Comment: no, the only ways I've used it were in the header file, and what i have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these 3 lines and it worked, i probably has something wrong with the array somewhere else.

```
 NSMutableArray *newMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[newMutableArray addObject:theString];

theMutableArray = newMutableArray;
```

Comment: Is this in your header (`.h`) file?

Comment: No , it's in a void method after getting the value of the text field input from an alert view

Comment: Okay. I can't help but ask where `theMutableArray` is initialized and if it is `static` or an `@property`?

Comment: The only initialization i am currently using is the theMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Answer (score 1):

You said that

```
NSLog(@"%@, %@", theString, theMutableArray);
```

returns "the string value", (null). So what do you expect? Your theMutableArray seems to be nil and this is a reason why you can not add anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make this a property of your class so that you can access it across the lifetime of its parent object and not just within one method. (I presume you want to access it in multiple methods).

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *theMutableArray;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation myClass

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.theMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (IBAction) anActionDidHappen:(id) sender {
    …
    theString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

    [self.theMutableArray addObject:theString];
}

@end
```